# "cbind" a dataframe to a spatial polygon

Tags: r, spatial

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with 10 features and a dataframe with 10 features. I simply want to "cbind" the dataframe to the end of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, but the normal cbind function outputs a dataframe - I'd like the output to be a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

```
cbind(polygons.SPDF,dataset.DF)
```

Comment: Probably because the class types differ, but we can't tell without a reproducible example. see: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/as.data.frame.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(maptools)
spCbind(polygons.SPDF, dataset.DF)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the row.names didn't match.

So in prep for the spCbind(), you need:

```
row.names(spatial.object)<-0:43
row.names(dataframe)<-0:43
```